# drupal ubercart order update django

Tags: django, drupal, ubercart

How would you update a django app when there was an order in drupal ubercart. The order details and user information gets carried to django app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We would need to know a **lot** more specifics about your setup in order to really answer this question, but it sounds like at a basic level all you need to do is use Drupal to modify another database (i.e., the one Django's using) and possibly redirect to the Django app?

If that's the case, then you'll need to write a small custom module that would:

1. Switch the active database to the one Django is using (this is relatively easy using [db_set_active()](http://drupal.org/node/18429))
2. Make your updates (can't help much here without knowing what your updates actually are, but either way, it will probably involve raw SQL)
3. Possibly redirect to a page in your Django app (depending on if the redirect is needed or if the user can stay within Drupal)

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, do you know what files need to be edited in ubercart to make updates, once the order is processed.

Comment: No files will be changed, just the DB, but either way you're probably better off just letting Ubercart do that by itself. Just switch to Django's DB, do Django stuff, switch back, and Ubercart will take it from there.